# Spring 3.2 Properties file reading dynamic property names (not auto injection)

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am using **Spring 3.2** and have added a property file which I have been able to use for injecting values into java class variables.

```
*<bean id="serverProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:mysetof.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="$server{" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
</bean>*

*@Value("#{$server{default.myproperty}}")
private double defaultMyProperty*
```

However I have some properties which I need to access dynamically.

How can I access these properties?  I have used the env variable

```
*/** Spring var - used for accessing properties. */
@Autowired
private Environment env;*
```

but I get null values returned when I try to do the following :

```
propertyValue = env.getProperty("default.myproperty");
```

What is the best approach for accessing property values directly and not auto injecting them.

These properties may or may not be present and there could be a huge number of them so therefore I do not wish to use autoinjection as this would involve setting up a huge list of variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the properties available in the environment use a `@PropertySource` to load them. A `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` will not add loaded properties to the `Environment` it will only add them to a internal `Properties` object.

Comment: I did have this - but I also had to add @Configuration tag for it to work - then it instantiated this bean twice (as I already had it in an context file).  Ideally looking for way to create a bean in context file ...?

Comment: Exclude `@Configuration` classes from being picked up with a `component-scan` or just drop all the xml and use Java Config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `CustomResourceBundleMessageSource` as below in `applicationContext.xml`
I've configured messages.properties file in `core-messageSource` bean and application-messages.properties file in `messageSource` bean

```
<bean id="core-messageSource"
        class="com.datacert.core.spring.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
        class="com.datacert.core.spring.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="parentMessageSource">
            <ref bean="core-messageSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>application-messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Then in your bean you can do as below

```
//I have security.cookie.timeout = 10 in my properties file
ResourceBundleMessageSource bean = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
bean.setBasename("application-messages");
String message = bean.getMessage("security.cookie.timeout", null, Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println("message = "+message)//will print message = 10
```

Comment: Is this meant to be used only for message strings ? I have properties that are numeric ...?

Comment: @NottmTony You can use resource bundle for any type. You can see in my case I was reading security.cookie.timeout property whose value is 10. I am parsing the string after reading from file as Integer.parseInt(message);